# Switching 400V motor with 5V

Tags: arduino, relay, automation, fluid-pump, contactor

I'am trying to make an automatic irrigation system using an Arduino, a moisture meter and a water pump.

The issue is that I can't figure out whether there is some relay/contactor type component that can control a 400 V device such as water pump using max 5V from Arduino in the controlling circuit. As far as I have researched it's quite common to use Arduino controlled relays to control contractors, but it seems this approach comes with challenges of its own, so any advice is welcome.

Comment: There are not many challenges if your 400V pump can be switched direct online with one 3 pole contactor. What is the exact technical hurdle you're up against?

Comment: Issue is that I am so very oblivious in electronics that I don't even know what keywords to use to research this so I am completely clueless wheter a contactor that can switch up to 400 V controlled by 5 V exists and whether there are some potential pitfalls to consider.

Comment: If you can't find a large contactor that will operate from 5V, you could use a small 5V relay to control the large contactor.

Comment: That's reasonable, thank you very much.

Comment: What about this guy, or three of them? https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-automation-and-safety/G2R-1-S-DC5-S/Z7764-ND/1789645

Comment: That' sounds great, thank you for the link.

Comment: Be aware of how much current they pull from 5 V, make sure you have ample decoupling and a freewheeling diode for each!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't find a contactor capable of switching a 400V motor with a 5V coil.
12V is already rare.

What you can do is cascade relays.
A small 5V pcb relay that operates a larger 24V contactor (with flyback diode).

Or use high side output driver from infineon for example.

Or use a digital method and control a frequency drive by modbus or signal relays.